# Movable ramp and moving up mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, friction

[image]

There exist a frictionless plane with block and ramp.

A block has mass m and the ramp has mass M.

The initial velocity of the block is $v_0$ and the ramp is at rest.

if there is no friction between block and ramp,

what are the velocities of block and ramp after they meet?

Since the block m moving upward, the momentum conservation law cannot be adapted.

Comment: Since no external forces act on the block-ramp system in the horizontal direction, we can conserve momentum in horizontal direction. And, which moment do you want the speed at? A common question is the moment at which the back and ramp move together.

Comment: If the momentum in the horizontal direction is conserved, the velocity of the block and ramp will be $mv_0$/(m+M) in the horizontal direction. Then, How can i determine the vertical speed of the block on the ramp???

Comment: Yes, at the moment that they both are moving together

Comment: if the block and ramp are attached and moving with the velocity $mv_0$/(m+M), the block cannot move upward the ramp. So the case of 
Inelasticity is not my concern.

Comment: what do you exactly need, the height reached or the velocity as a function of height?

Comment: You cannot solve this problem without knowing the angle of the ramp.

Comment: I just need the speed of block and ramp when they just meet. The direction of block is changed by the ramp. I don't know how the speed is determined. The angle of the ramp is $\theta$